# windows virtual machine using dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, virtualbox, windows

I have a partition with windows for dual boot and I want use that instalation in a VM. Can I do this?

I know that OS X has a software (Parallels) that creates a VM using a installation that you have already in one partition but in ubuntu I cannot find anything.

I'm asking this because I don't want to have another windows installation.

Thank you

Comment: It is possible and I have done it successfully with VirtualBox using the comprehensive guide https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Dualboot-Windows_virtualisieren/ (German). It contains instructions to make your VM look like your real hardware to Windows, so you can switch running it natively and virtualized without the need to reactivate your Windows copy. (However, this feature stopped working for me later.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a VM from your machine using from VMware the 'vCenter Converter'. This will create a virtual machine from your physical machine.
https://www.vmware.com/de/products/converter.html
This product should be free. To download you have to register.
If you want to create a Virtual Box machine, you can use this VM to create a new Virtual Box machine.